# Is there a way to rewrite a cookie name in nginx?

Tags: cookies, nginx, session-cookies, httpcookie, cookie-httponly

I'm trying to logout the user by removing a cookie and redirect him to the home page.

Is it possible to do it without adding lua-nginx-module?

Answer (score 0):

Starting in 1.1.15, proxy_cookie_domain option was added to address this issue.

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule#proxy_cookie_domain

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain

Yes it is possible with lua-nginx-module also

Comment: Can you explain how exactly proxy_cookie_domain helps in invalidating the cookie?